# Can I own shares in a company while under a study permit in Canada and can the company sponsor or assist me in getting a PR?

Tags: canada, resident-permit, student-visa, students, startups

Is it possible for me to own shares in a company as an international student on study permit? The majority of the shares will owned be by a Canadian resident. Also can this help me get a PR through any program such as the startup visa?

Comment: Nothing is stopping you owning shares in a company while you are studying in Canada. You would not be permitted to do any work of any kind for the company unless your visa permits it.